# Nano Assault Ex 3DS Cluster 5 Cell 3

Tags: nano-assault

I was wondering if anyone has any tips for cluster 5 cell 3. I get to 3 active organisms which are three flying rotating things that drop bombs but I can't seem to kill them and there's 1 infected region left also. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Cheers Antcast that worked. Can finally get past that level! 

Answer (score -1):

You have to shoot the nubs on the ground when those flying things are.over them to make them explode